# Is there any relation between the tangent to a curve and the trigonometric $~\tan(x)~$ function?

Tags: trigonometry

This question has pestered me in the past, on whether the trigonometric identity $~\tan(x)~$ has anything to do with the tangent line to a curve or whether the naming is purely a coincidence and unrelated.

It has recently been brought back to my mind when I was reading about tangent spaces.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  I think you mean the trigonometric *function*. 
 The line $x=1$ is tangent to the unit circle, and $\tan(\theta)$ is the length of the segment of that line between the line $y=0$ and the line $y=\tan(\theta)x$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got the right answer in a comment but I thought a picture might help:

[image]

The tangent of the red angle is the length of the red line, which is tangent to the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

[Tangent](http://www.nabla.hr/FU-CFunDerivative2.htm)

In differential calculus the slope of secant (s) becomes the slope of a special line when intersection points are made to be coincident.. forming  a tangent line (t) shown when the point is a double point.

Angle of slope $\alpha_1$ becomes $\alpha_2$. The line and curve have same slope but different curvature.

The tangent straight line has slope equalling $ \dfrac{dy}{dx}= \tan \alpha_2$

From tangential contact's unique appearance probably the name of trig function *tangent* has been derived or adopted.

Answer (score 0):

The answer explaining it in terms of slopes has a good approach, but a more graphical way of answering your question is using the unit circle. I thought it would be easy to find a video explaining this, but it looks like most videos just define the tangent as the division of sine and cosine, namely 
$$ \tan \theta= \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} $$
, including the videos that focus on the unit circle.

However, I found the video titled ["Is a tangent to a circle related to the trig function tan?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-tsSJx-P18&t=180s), by someone named Todd Federman, and I think it is a good visual explanation.